# XSLT to remove an element but not its children?

Tags: xml, xslt

**Input:**

```
<req>
  <element>
   <field1>abcd</field1>
   <field2>05/05/2020</field2>
  </element>
</req>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<req>
  <field1>abcd</field1>
  <field2>05/05/2020</field2>
</req>
```

So my requirement is to remove `element` from the input XML.

Comment: You're supposed to show your code attempt, and similar questions have probably been already asked, but with your first question in over 6 years here being about XSLT, I couldn't bring myself to vote to close.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/req">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="element/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Right, if simpler suffices, simpler is better (+1).   OTOH, if there's a need to *copy everything as-is except...* `element`, or if the heritage of `element` might vary, then the identity transformation approach is a better fit (and still relatively simple, at least conceptually).

Answer (score 2):

Think identity transform when you see such problems:

This XSLT,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Indent output: -->
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Cleanup extra whitespace in output: -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- If not overridden, copy node as-is: -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Override to treat element specially: Just like identity
       template but omit xsl:copy: -->
  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input XML,

```
<req>
  <element>
    <field1>abcd</field1>
    <field2>05/05/2020</field2>
  </element>
</req>
```

produces your output XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<req>
   <field1>abcd</field1>
   <field2>05/05/2020</field2>
</req>
```

as requested.