# PowerPoint VBA Event SelectionChange Not Triggered by SVG (Graphics) Selection

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm encountering a peculiar issue in PowerPoint VBA where the **`SelectionChange`** event does not seem to get triggered when SVG files (treated as Graphics elements) are selected or deselected. This behavior is inconsistent with how the event responds to other types of objects, like shapes or text boxes.

## Issue Description:

In my PowerPoint VBA project, I rely on the App_WindowSelectionChange event to detect when the user selects different objects on a slide. This is crucial for the functionality of my add-in, as it updates the Ribbon UI based on the current selection. This is already workaround, since I first encountered the error when using the  **`getVisible`** method within the CustomUI.xml.

I am trying to manipulate the Ribbon, here is a simplified version of my event handler:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
' Code to update Ribbon based on selection
End Sub
```

This setup works as expected for standard PowerPoint objects like shapes and text boxes. However, when SVG files *or more specifically Graphics objects* are selected, the event does not fire. As a result, my Ribbon UI does not update correctly in response to SVG selections.

### Troubleshooting Attempts:

- I confirmed that the event handler works for other types of objects.
- No error messages are thrown; the event simply does not trigger for SVG file selections.
- I experimented with different types of selections and found the issue is specific to Graphics (SVGs).
- One way to mitigate the problem is to convert the Graphic into a Shape. The SVGs are however centered on a square canvas and converting them into Shapes does not keep this canvas.

## Possible Limitation:

I think, that PowerPoint may have a limitation or oversight in its event handling mechanism, specifically concerning SVG files. Unlike standard shapes, SVGs might be treated differently internally, leading to this discrepancy in event triggering.

## Seeking Solutions:

I am looking for a workaround or solution to reliably detect SVG file (Icons) selections in PowerPoint. My goal is to have the Ribbon UI respond to these selections just as it does for other objects.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into how PowerPoint handles SVG files  in terms of event handling, your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I'd strongly suggest using Help | Send Feedback in PowerPoint itself to report the problem to Microsoft. That gets the report to the developers. I would include a link to your post here.

Comment: Have you tested with other graphic formats, like EMF, JPG, PNG, etc.? If the problem is not specific to SVGs but rather to all graphic objects, then your bug report should mention that. Use File>Feedback>Send a Frown to generate a report. MS is unlikely to reply.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem, App_WindowSelectionChange event is firing for svg images just as for anything else for me. Could it be a problem with the svg files you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, basically .svg images are invisible through VBA. This is probably due to the fact that they are simply embedded into the slide, but the "real" image is stored in the PowerPoint file.

You mentioned a canvas, present in the original .svg file, that does not get translated into DrawingML by PowerPoint (through the ribbon button "Convert to Shape"). Such canvas is either

- within a "clipPath" tag or
- has the attribute "style = display:none".

The solution I would suggest would be

- remove the "clipPath" tag (though not its content) or
- remove the relevant part of the "style" attribute

the above can be done manually or through code (either directly with VBA or with [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095536/18247317)) (I found only for the tag, for the attribute you would have to look around)

- convert the .svg, once imported, into shapes (which then you could set to invisible in PowerPoint), the square will be converted, too, and you will just have to set its fill and line to "none".

For reference, should you be interested, [here](http://officeopenxml.com/drwShape.php) some information about how shapes are encoded in OOXML.